# Jekyll Assets - CssSyntaxError - Unclosed string

Tags: css, jekyll

I am working on a static website which is using Jekyll to generate htmls. I am using jekyll-assets for managing the stylesheets, javascripts and images.

It was all working fine untill I added a CSS file. It started giving me CssSyntaxError while building.

Here is the snippet from the CSS file where the error is pointing.

```
div.dark_rounded .pp_top .pp_middle,div.dark_rounded .pp_content,div.dark_rounded .pp_bottom .pp_middle {
  background: url(image-path("prettyPhoto/dark_rounded/contentPattern.png")) top left repeat;
}
```

And here is the error which I am getting

```
CssSyntaxError:
/src/_assets/css/global.css:13717:74: Unclosed string 13715 | 13716 | div.dark_rounded .pp_top .pp_middle,div.dark_rounded 
.pp_content,div.dark_rounded .pp_bottom .pp_middle { > 13717 | background: url(image-path("prettyPhoto/dark_rounded/contentPattern.png")) top left repeat; | ^ 13718 | } 13719 | 

jekyll 3.3.0 | Error:  CssSyntaxError: /src/_assets/css/global.css:13717:74: Unclosed string

  13715 | 
  13716 | div.dark_rounded .pp_top .pp_middle,div.dark_rounded .pp_content,div.dark_rounded .pp_bottom .pp_middle {
> 13717 |   background: url(image-path("prettyPhoto/dark_rounded/contentPattern.png")) top left repeat;
        |                                                                          ^
  13718 | }
  13719 |
```

I am unable to find any unclosed string here.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you remove these 3 lines everything works correctly?

Comment: It might be due to you using .css? I believe the image-path helper is a sass function and I'm not entirely sure if jekyll-assets processes all stylesheet files including .css files through sass.